# ADFS & Shibboleth Sp test environment

Tags: windows-7, adfs, shibboleth

Is there any possibility to create a test invirounment for Shibboleth SP and ADFS (SAML 2.0) Claims provider on windows 7 operating system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Shibboleth SP - Yes.
- ADFS - No - requires Windows Server 64 bit.

Comment: strictly speaking windows 2008 sp2 x86 would do to get ad fs 2.0 :) If its a lab, a trial virtual machine might suffice. You can download Windows 2012 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/trial.aspx